# What does 'NO_DSN' option mean in creating DB server connection?

Tags: php, mysql

In TestLink, I found a `NO_DSN` option in Database connection in `installNewDB.php` script. I never heard of `NO_DSN` and would like to know if someone can explain it to me:

see Lines 163 - 180 (https://github.com/viglesiasce/testlink/blob/master/install/installNewDB.php):

```
// Connect to DB Server without choosing an specific database
$db = new database($db_type);
define('NO_DSN',FALSE);
@$conn_result = $db->connect(NO_DSN,$db_server, $db_admin_name, $db_admin_pass); 
if( $conn_result['status'] == 0 ) 
{
    echo '<span class="notok">Failed!</span><p />Please check 
                              the database login details and try again.';
    echo '<br>Database Error Message: ' . $db->error_msg() . "<br>";

    close_html_and_exit();
} 
else 
{
    echo "<span class='ok'>OK!</span><p />";
}
$db->close();
$db=null;
```

What does it mean here?: define('**NO_DSN**',FALSE);

and here: $db->connect(**NO_DSN**,$db_server, $db_admin_name, $db_admin_pass);

Comment: its particular to the code you are using, you would have to find its usage in that code.

Answer (score -1):

In this case DSN refers to 'Data source name'.

It can be an optional connection string that you pass to the database to set additional options like db driver, host, db name, charset, port, etc..

An example of a DSN string using PDO would be like this:

`mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;port=3306;charset=utf8mb4`

So in your case it looks like the 'NO_DSN' option is defaulting to false unless you specify the connection string.

Answer (score -2):

DNS is a server that translates websites' addresses so that your browser can connect to them. If the addresses become out-of-date or theserver has issues, you'll encounter aDNS error and won't be able to connect to a specific site or group of sites even with Internet access.

Comment: DSN =Data Source Name. not DNS